# Save Current Docusaurus Page as PDF

Tags: pdf, button, markdown, docusaurus

I am making a project with Docusaurus using markdown to create the pages inside of it and I had an idea but idk if it's possible.

The idea is to create some kind of button or link to Download the current page as PDF.

Does anynone know if its possible to do that? Maybe there is a docusaurus plugging or some kind of library that it can be used.
Thanks

Comment: but there is no html code in my pages, all of them are in markdown

Comment: it is a stream browser displaing the images and the simple solution is indeed to just let them print what they want, but my idea was to get it done wihtout needing to click CTRL+P and selecting "Save as PDF", just a single button on the page to handle all that. I think this would improve the Site's UX